# Function to copy char pointer content crashes when printing second index of copy

Tags: c, string, pointers, malloc

I am having problems copying the content pointed by a char pointer to another, even though I am allocating memory to it before using **strcpy**. I've seen somy suggestions with **strdup**, but I would like to know what to do without the need of it. Here is my main code

```
int main (void)
{
    char word[20];
    leaftype destiny;
    while(1)
    {
        printf("\nType in a word: ");
        scanf("%s",word);
        copy_leaf(&destiny,palavra);
        if (palavra[0] == '0') break;
    }

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

The problem I have is with the function copy_leaf:

```
void copy_leaf(leaftype* destiny, leaftype source)
{
    printf("\n====start of copy_leaf======\n");
    int i;
    printf("strlen of source: %d",strlen(source));
    printf("\nsource: ");
    for(i = 0; i <= strlen(source); i++)
    {
        if(i == strlen(source))
        {
            printf("\\0");
        }
        else printf("%c-",source[i]);
    }
    *destiny = malloc((strlen(source)+1)*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(*destiny,source);
    printf("\nstrlen of destiny: %d",strlen(*destiny));
    printf("\ndestiny: ");
    for(i = 0; i <= strlen(*destiny); i++)
    {
        if(i == strlen(*destiny))
        {
        printf("\\0");
        }
        else printf("%c-",*destiny[i]);
    }
    printf("\n===end of copy_leaf======\n");
}
```

leaftype is defined as:

```
typedef char* leaftype;
```

When I run the code having the word "example" as input, I get on the console:

```
Type in a word: 
====start of copy_leaf======
strlen of source: 7
source: e-x-a-m-p-l-e-\0
strlen of destiny: 7
destiny: e-
```

and it crashes ("program.exe has stopped working etc" on Windows 7). I am using devcpp, but my file is named with C extension. Can anyone help me in fixing this char* to char* content copy? I need a function to make that because I need to copy content of one string to another many times in my C file. Thanks in advance!

p.s.: what I have already tried in **copy_leaf** function (desperate solutions):

- changing **leaftype source** to **const leaftype source** (that'd be a **const char* source**)
- making ***destiny = strcpy(*destiny,source)**, as strcpy returns a pointer to the destination string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
printf("%c-",*destiny[i]);
```

`destiny` is a char**, and [] has precedence over *.

Therefore this is interpreted as:

```
printf("%c-",*(destiny[i]));
```

when you actually want:

```
printf("%c-", (*destiny)[i]);
```

i.e. you were reading the first element of the ith pointer, when you actually wanted the ith element of the first (and only) pointer.

Answer (score 4):

you should not use `*destiny[i]`, but you need to use `(*destiny)[i]` like in this line,

```
    else printf("%c-",(*destiny)[i]);
```

BTW, destiny is a double pointer, i don't think you really need a double pointer anyway.

Comment: I'll +1 this if you explain what the difference is in a way that a novice can understand ;)

Comment: A double pointer is necessary as stated [here](http://c-faq.com/ptrs/passptrinit.html)

Answer (score 0):

Why I like that?
These are the following corrections to be done.

```
 void copy_leaf(leaftype* destiny, leaftype source)
```

change to

```
void copy_leaf(leaftype destiny, leaftype source)

destiny = malloc((strlen(source)+1)*sizeof(char));

strcpy(destiny,source);


for(i = 0; i < strlen(destiny); i++)
    {
        printf("%c-",destiny[i]);


    }
```

By the way, the right prototype for strcpy should be that the source data should be always- const char *.

Comment: That changes the behavior. In the OP's version destiny is modified in the caller. You're now only modifying a local copy.

Comment: Also, the second argument to strcpy is const char*, but that means that strcpy doesn't modify the data. There's no requirement that the caller use a const char*; a char* is compatible.